# Sqlite: select, join using like for the join fields

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-like

This is in sqlite 3
I have location numbers and addresses in one table (stored as CHAR)
I have device names and other details in another table, where device names are stored as CHAR and the location number is a substring or equal with the device name

I would like to be able to select all the locations and calculate the number of devices that are at that location based,grouped by the location number

Here is what I am using

> ```
> SELECT v.[TransitNumber],DeviceName,count(NeighborName) from Neighbors n
> left join VirtualControllers v on v.TransitNumber like '%'+n.DeviceName+'%'
> group by DeviceName
> ```

This returns me Null for the value of the transit number and I don't undertand why

Here is some data

```
TransitNumber   DeviceName  count(NeighborName)  
                712bs1       2  
                712bs2       2
```

the transit number should have been 712 In this case (BTW I am actually counting how many PC are connected to each device but I would like to get how many PCs are in that location
The result should be

```
TransitNumber   count(NeighborName)
712               4
```

Here is some data example and what I want to achieve

```
    Neighbours table

    DeviceName  Interface   NeighbourName
    us712bs1        fa0/1       PC1
    us712bs1        fa0/2       PC2
    us712bs2        fa0/1       PC3
    us712bs2        fa0/2       PC4


   VirtualCotroller table

    TransitNumber   Address
    712             New York, TimeSquare


    Expected result 

    TransitNumber   PCs
    712             4
```

Comment: Why are you using an outer join?

Comment: Because I am a not a programmer, as you can guess I am on the support /infrastructure side and I am toying with programming (python mostly) to make my life easier A simple join did not work, I don;t know why. I added "left" and I got results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/30ace/6/5) is a fiddle with what you want.

I've left it as a left outer join as this will mean you will get counts of zero included for VirtualControllers that have no Neighbours (rather than just exclude the missing rows - if you want to exclude them change it to be an INNER JOIN)

The main issue was your concatenation in your LIKE, SQLite uses double pipe || for string concatenation not +.

There are two selects in the fiddle above, the first gives what you asked for, with the count of 4. The second also groups by the device name, in case you wanted to see the distinction between the two.

Your SQL ends up being as follows:

```
SELECT TransitNumber, DeviceName, COUNT (NeighbourName)
FROM VirtualController V
LEFT OUTER JOIN Neighbours N ON N.DeviceName LIKE '%' || V.TransitNumber || '%'
GROUP BY TransitNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamie, it worked. My mistake was because I used the Python syntax to concatenate strings. Had I tried this in a python script it would have worked but I continued to play with the query from SQL command line and it failed :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `DeviceName` belongs to which table? `Neighbors`? If so, you need to use the **foreign key** that references `Neighbors` on `VirtualControllers` in order to make the `JOIN` and then use the `LIKE` in a `WHERE` clause. I will pretend you have a `fk_id_neighbor` on the `VirtualControllers` table and `id_neighbor` on `Neighbor` table. Something like this should work

```
SELECT n.DeviceName, n.Id_Neighbor, count(n.NeighborName) AS qtd, v.TransitNumber, v.FK_Id_Neighbor

FROM Neighbors n

LEFT JOIN VirtualControllers AS v ON v.TransitNumber.FK_Id_Neighbor= 
n.Id_Neighbor

WHERE v.TransitNumber LIKE '%'+n.DeviceName+'%'

GROUP BY n.DeviceName
```

You could use `CONCAT` in the `LIKE` statement but I do not recommend.

Comment: Hi Diefani
I am sorry but I do not have those fields or keys in my tables
I just quoted above a sample of the type of data that I am dealing with

Comment: Try this and see if it works...

SELECT  v.TransitNumber, n.DeviceName,COUNT(n.NeighborName)
FROM VirtualController v
JOIN Neighbors AS n ON v.TransitNumber LIKE '%'+n.DeviceName+'%'
ORDER BY n.DeviceName;

Comment: worse than my own; returned zero results

Comment: Delete the GROUP BY DeviceName and I think you will get what you need...Right now I'm a computer where I have no SQLite, only MySQL Workbench and indeed my code above returned no results but when I used this one 

SELECT n.DeviceName,COUNT(n.NeighbourName), v.TransitNumber 
FROM Neighbors n 
LEFT JOIN VirtualController AS v ON n.DeviceName LIKE CONCAT('%', v.TransitNumber,'%')

I get the result you need, so just don't use ORDER BY or GROUP BY and I believe you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This comparison is wrong:

```
v.TransitNumber like '%'+n.DeviceName+'%'
```

When you try it with some example values, you get:

```
'712' LIKE '%us712bs1%'
```

But you want it the other way around:

```
'us712bs1' LIKE '%712%'
```

i.e.:

```
n.DeviceName like '%'+v.TransitNumber+'%'
```

Comment: it produces almost the same result and the transit number continues to be empty..